# Avoid duplicates

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0

how can i avoid duplicates from a string (in c#)
 eg.i have a,a,b,b,c i want to get the answer like a,b,c

Comment: Duplicates from a string in what?

Comment: i have a string like a,a,b,b,c i want to avoid duplicates.ie,i want to get answer like a,b,c

Answer (score 4):

By using [`HashSet<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [List<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and the [Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb919166.aspx) method to check for this.

Declare it as

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

and check as

```
if (!list.Contains(stringValue))
   list.Add(stringValue);
```

Comment: Note: This algorithm is O(n^2) for populating a list with n elements. Only use for small lists.