# avoid duplicates from array

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Avoid duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264469/avoid-duplicates)

hi al,
 i want to avoid duplicate entries from array.....(in c#)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264469/avoid-duplicates

Answer (score 1):

Use Distinct method:

```
public static void DistinctExample()
{
    string[] names = new string[] { "Peter", "Paul", "Mary", 
        "Peter", "Paul", "Mary", "Janet" };

    var q = (from s in names
            select s).Distinct();

    foreach (var name in q) {
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use linq
http://blogs.msdn.com/ericwhite/archive/2008/08/19/find-duplicates-using-linq.aspx